# Refresh parent without closing popup

Tags: javascript

I use the gettopup.com popup.

Before I give a header in php for a redirect, I have te following javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
window.parent.location.reload();
</script>
```

This should refresh the parent page without closing te popup, but nothing happens.
What is wrong with it?

Comment: I think you should have something like `window.opener.location.reload()`. `.parent()` is for (i)frames.

Answer (score 0):

It is not `.parent()` that you want but `window.opener`:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
    window.opener.location.reload();
</script>
```

Comment: Does not work I'm afraid. It refreshes when the page is closed, but not before the redirect.