# Refresh main window without closing popup in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I need to refresh a html page while the popup is still open, I am using a jsp page with spring mvc is there any way to refresh the parent page while the popup is still open? The same question was asked in this[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282110/refresh-parent-without-closing-popup) but the answer does not work. Is this achievable?

Comment: Depends on the pop-up. If it's a real window, then yes, but if the pop-up is an HTML element on the page to refresh, then not possible.

Comment: You cannot `.reload()` the window in this way and retain the HTML Elements. See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload You can create a page container in your HTML and use `.load()` to replace the elements in the container. Maybe an `<iframe>` would be useful? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example